# How to solve this: GIT doesn't notice changes in files that are actually changed

Tags: git

I'm very unfamiliar with GIT having switched over form SVN quite recently so might be screwing something obvious up here

Some changes it notices, but once they've been committed there are lots it just doesn't see

there's significant differences in at least 4 files I have right now and both Tortoise and Git Status on command line notice nothing different in the files, but if I Diff through Git (in tortoise) they list the changes (i'm not clever enough to get git diff to work on the command-line for the files)

this has happened a few times and I get around it by Git Cloning into a clean folder and copying my old files over it, but it seems like gradually it degrades and starts ignoring changes all over again. it seems ridiculous... is there some why I can fix this or is there something I'm likely doing wrong?

----------- extra info

```
$ git status --ignored
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../deploy.txt
#       ../test.rar
# Ignored files:
#   (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../.idea/
#       ../project.iml
#       ../project.iws
#       ../project.log
#       ../logs/
#       ../target/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

---

```
$ git config --local -l
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url={my url}
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Did you `git add -a *`?

Comment: please show an example of you issuing `git diff <file>` and the differences you're expecting to see. It sounds like you may be committing changes without realizing.

Comment: see if the file is excluded with .gitignore?

Comment: git diff | 

git diff <myfile> | 

git diff HEAD^^ <myfile> | 

essentially I dont know that command.

Changes are NOT committed. I guarantee that. I can look in my repository and I can do a clean checkout and see the changes aren't there.

Comment: files are definitely not git-ignored, are in the repository and visible, and nothing like that in the git-ignore

Comment: files definitely all added

they are in the repository and visible and don't have the changes, but the changes aren't registered by Git and Git status gives says no changes. It's as though the repository is corrupted or something weird I don't understand

Comment: Please show the output of `git status --ignored`.

Comment: I've added the git status --ignored to the description above

the two files it mentions are not needed and are not the files that actually have changes in that it isn't noticing. Nothing mentioned there is. they are just .java files.

Comment: `git ls-files path/to/a-missing-file`.  What OS are you on? `git config --local -l`. `git diff --cached -- path/to/a-missing-file; git diff -- path/to/a-missing-file`. Post the results of all those (you can just do the hunk headers without the content).  Ah, I see Tortoise so Windows.  ***Is this on a `*FAT` filesystem***?

Comment: git ls-files {file} lists {file} once.
I'm on Win8.
Git config --local l I've added to info above.
Git diff {file} = nothing.
Git diff -- {file} = nothing.
Git diff --cached {file} = nothing.
Git diff --cached -- {file} = nothing.

Comment: I don't know if it's significant but it's possible there are CFLF vs LF endings creeping in the source from a client's code-base. This couldn't affect this stuff could it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im pretty sure this is caused by 'assume unchanged' flag

i didnt know how to use tortoise svn properly and was clicking 'assume no change' when i got files that had 0 lines added and 0 removed - basically caused by line endings between two different file systems screwing things up. I thought I was telling it 'for this commit just consider this file hasnt really had anything done to it' - which of course is right for CRLF line endings. of course i've since worked out it what it actually does, which is basically just ignoring any future changes

also explains why checking out clean would solve it for a while